# HiveQL: counting instancees of values above range inside array

Tags: arrays, count, hive, hiveql

Let's say I have two tables

T1:

```
id    number
A     1  
B     1
C     4
A     6
A     9
```

T2:

```
id
A
B
C
```

What i do now is join them and produce a list of all numbers each of the IDs have in TB1.

```
SELECT T2.id, collect_list(T1.number)
FROM T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 on T1.id = T2.id
GROUP BY T2.id
```

So now I have this:

Result:

```
id    number
A     [1, 6, 9]  
B     [1]
C     [4]
```

What if I wanted to also output the count of times number for each id exceeded, say, 5? I want to get another table from RESULT table.

So:

Result2:

```
id    number       count_above_5
A     [1, 6, 9]    2
B     [1]          0
C     [4]          0
```

I know that I can explode the array and then produce a new table  WHERE number>5 and count instances of those rows per ID and then I can join the result table above with this one, but is there a cleaner, nicer way to do this? As in, can I apply some function on the column with the array to produce count_above_5?

Comment: Both `6` and `9` are greater than `5`. `count_above_5` should be equal `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `count`

```
SELECT T2.id, collect_list(T1.number),count(case when T1.number > 5 then 1 end) as count_above_5
FROM T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 on T1.id = T2.id
GROUP BY T2.id
```